# is it possible to set alternate row backcolor on a jqgrid Treegrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, treegrid

i am starting to play around with jqGrid Treegrid but i don't see anyway to set alternative row back color.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean `altRows` and `altclass` parameters, then there not works. To be exactly at the tree grid initialization time (inside of `setTreeGrid`) some jqGrid parameters will be reset. How you can see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.1/js/grid.treegrid.js#L132) the value of the `altRows` parameter will be set to `false`. The reason of the change would be clear if you imagine that expanding/collapsing of tree nodes can change the order of the tree items so you would be have

[image]

from the original tree

[image]

**UPDATED**: A workaround is always exist. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AdjacencyTreeAltRows.htm) with the following code:

```
var resetAltRows = function () {
    // I think one can improve performance the function a little if needed,
    // but it should be done the same
    $(this).children("tbody:first").children('tr.jqgrow').removeClass('myAltRowClass');
    $(this).children("tbody:first").children('tr.jqgrow:visible:odd').addClass('myAltRowClass');
};
$("#tree").jqGrid({
    url: 'AdjacencyTreeAltRows.json',
    datatype:'json',
    mtype:'GET',
    colNames: ["ID", 'Description', "Total"],
    colModel: [
        {name:'id', index:'id', width: 1, hidden: true, key: true},
        {name:'desc', width:180, sortable:false},
        {name:'num', width:80, sortable:false, align:'center'}
    ],
    treeGridModel:'adjacency',
    height:'auto',
    //altRows: true,
    //altclass: 'myAltRowClass',
    rowNum: 10000,
    treeGrid: true,
    ExpandColumn:'desc',
    loadComplete: function() {
        var grid = this;
        resetAltRows.call(this);
        $(this).find('tr.jqgrow td div.treeclick').click(function(){
            resetAltRows.call(grid);
        });
        $(this).find('tr.jqgrow td span.cell-wrapper').click(function(){
            resetAltRows.call(grid);
        });
    },
    ExpandColClick: true,
    caption:"TreeGrid Test"
});
```

Comment: that was my whole point as when you expand collapse you would need to reset the altRow colors.  do you see any workaround s?

Comment: thanks . . i am a bit concerned with performance of this but thanks for the update