# How to change the color of a particular row in treeGrid

Tags: jqgrid, treegrid

I want to change the color of a particular row in jQgrid/treeGrid. can anyone share the code for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works exactly like with other jqGrids. Look at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507094/is-it-possible-to-set-alternate-row-backcolor-on-a-jqgrid-treegrid/6509495#6509495). With respect of `addClass('...')` to `<tr>` elements the background color can be changed.

Comment: I am not defining any <tr> in my code. I am using rowid in my code. can you help me?

Comment: @manish987654321: grid rows will be represented as HTML `<tr>` (table row) elements. If you has `rowid` of the row, which choler you want change, `$('#'+rowid).addClass('myAltRowClass');`