# jqGrid altRows - Every two rows

Tags: jqgrid, zebra-striping

I am outputting a jqGrid and need to alternate row colors but rather than the common every-other-row, I need to alternate every-two-rows.  Two rows of one color, followed by two rows of another color and then switch back to the first color and so on...

Here's a sample of what I need to achieve...

Sample grid:

```
+-------------------+
| row color 'black' |
| row color 'black' |
| row color 'white' |
| row color 'white' |
| row color 'black' |
| row color 'black' |
| row color 'white' |
| row color 'white' |
+-------------------+
```

Seems there must be more to it than jqGrid's altRows and altclass.

Thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's interesting question! In general `rowattr` callback is the best way to assign attributes (for example class attribute) to the rows, but `rowattr` callback in the current implementation of jqGrid has no information about the index of the row. So one have to set `altclass` inside of `loadComplete`.

To set standard `altclass` one can use the following

```js
loadComplete: function () {
    $(this).find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow:visible:odd").addClass("myAltRowClass");
}
```

You can use the code in case of alternating TreeGrid (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6509495/315935)) or Grouping for example.

If you need to alternate every-two-rows then you can use custom [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead of `:odd`. For example [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomAltRows.htm) uses

```js
loadComplete: function () {
    $(this).find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow:visible")
        .filter(function (i) {
            return i % 4 >= 2;
        })
        .addClass("myAltRowClass");
}
```

and it displays the following grid

[image]

Comment: This is simple and works exactly as needed.  Thanks a bunch Oleg!

Comment: @Oleg can you look up at this question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924180/jqgrid-edit-method-doesnt-fire-up-second-time