# jqGrid save method doesnt fire up after error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a grid which does check for duplicate Number in the grid. Which i acheived successfully however after my program checks for duplicate barcode i restore the row and try to edit again to let user re-enter correct barcode but the enter key event doesnt fire up this time on edit method

**Steps to reproduce what i get are below**

Please see code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xdUpn/). To see what error i am getting please enter a number in first row (first column is only editable in grid) and enter the same number in the second row and it will give error saying duplicate barcode so i want user to change the number but it doesnot fire up editMethod at this point ? Help Please

code :

```
var portalBarcodeGrid = namespace.extend(com,'com.barcodeGrid');
```

portalBarcodeGrid = {

```
    /*requestInfo : {
    reOpenMode : true,
    NextApplicableStep : 'SHIP_LOAN',
    RequestNumber : 'PAT_10000165',
    LoanTrackingInfo : [
          {LocalNumber : 'LON1', LoanStatusComplete :  true },
          {LocalNumber : 'LON2', LoanStatusComplete :  true },
          {LocalNumber : 'LON3', LoanStatusComplete :  true },
          {LocalNumber : 'LON4', LoanStatusComplete :  true },
          {LocalNumber : 'LON5', LoanStatusComplete :  true },
    ]
},*/

requestInfo : {
    NextApplicableStep : 'SHIP_LOAN',
    RequestNumber : 'PAT_10000165',
    LoanTrackingInfo : [

    ]
},

 requestProcessStatus : {
     LoanTrackingInfo : [
         //{LocalNumber : '', ProcessStatus :  ''}
     ]
 },

 processStatus : {
        PENDING : 'Pending',
        PROCESSING : 'Processing',
        PROCESSSUCCESS : 'Process Success',
        PROCESSFAILED : 'Process Failed',
        UNDOSUCCESS : 'Undo Success',
        UNDOFAILED : 'Undo Failed'
},

initializeBarcodeGrid : function( gridSelector ) {
    $(gridSelector).jqGrid({
        datatype : "local",
        width : 'auto',
        height : 'auto',
        gridview : true,
        shrinkToFit : true,
        colNames : [ 'Barcode', 'Status' ],
        colModel : [ {name : 'LocalNumber',resizable : false,sortable : false, editoptions: { maxlength: 15 }}, 
                     {name : 'ProcessStatus',resizable : false,sortable : false}, 
                    ],
        onSelectRow : function(rowId, status, e) {
            portalBarcodeGrid.onBarcodeGridSelectRow( gridSelector, rowId );
        },
        editurl: 'clientArray',
    });

    // apply height and width rules to parent of the grid
    $(gridSelector).parents('div.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').css("max-height","120px");
    $(gridSelector).parents('div.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').css("max-width","480px");
    $(gridSelector).parents('div.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').css("overflow-x","hidden");
},



selectBarcodeGridRow : function ( rowId ) {
    console.log(" selectBarcodeGridRow ");
    var gridSelector =  '#'+ portalBarcodeGrid.getGridSelectorId( rowId );
    $( gridSelector ).jqGrid( "setSelection", rowId, true );
},


getGridSelectorId : function ( rowId ){
    return $( '#' +rowId ).closest( 'table' ).attr( 'id' );

},

onBarcodeGridSelectRow : function ( gridSelector, rowId ) {
    console.log(" onBarcodeGridSelectRow ");
    var currentRowNum = rowId.split('-')[1];
    var editableRowId = $( gridSelector ).find( ':input' ).parent().parent().attr( 'id' );
    var editableRowNum = 0;

    if(editableRowId)
        editableRowNum = editableRowId.split( '-' )[ 1 ];

    if( editableRowId && editableRowId != rowId ){

        //portalBarcodeGrid.selectBarcodeGridRow( gridSelector, editableRowId );
        $( gridSelector ).jqGrid( 'saveRow', editableRowId, '', '', '', portalBarcodeGrid.getRowData );

        //portalBarcodeGrid.selectBarcodeGridRow( gridSelector, rowId );
        var prevTdText = $.trim( $( '#'+editableRowId ).find( 'td:first' ).text() );

        if(prevTdText.length > 0 && ++editableRowNum == currentRowNum ){
            var gridDataObj = $( gridSelector ).jqGrid( 'getRowData', rowId );

            if(gridDataObj && gridDataObj.ProcessStatus ==  portalBarcodeGrid.processStatus.PROCESSSUCCESS)
                $( gridSelector ).jqGrid( 'editRow', rowId, true, portalBarcodeGrid.addRows( rowId ), '', '', '' , portalBarcodeGrid.getRowData );
        }
        return;
    }
    else{
        var gridDataObj = $( gridSelector ).jqGrid( 'getRowData', rowId );

        if( gridDataObj.ProcessStatus !=  portalBarcodeGrid.processStatus.PROCESSSUCCESS && ( portalBarcodeGrid.requestInfo.NextApplicableStep == 'SHIP_LOAN' || portalBarcodeGrid.requestInfo.NextApplicableStep == 'RECEIVE_LOAN' )  ){
            portalBarcodeGrid.addEditableProperty( gridSelector, rowId );
        }
        else{
            portalBarcodeGrid.putValueInTextBox( '#txtBarcode',gridDataObj.LocalNumber );
        }
    }
},

putValueInTextBox : function( selector,barcode ) {
    $( selector ).val( barcode );
},


addInitialGridRecord : function ( gridSelector ) {
    if( portalBarcodeGrid.requestInfo.reOpenMode == true ){
        portalBarcodeGrid.createBarcodeGridRows( gridSelector, portalBarcodeGrid.requestInfo.LoanTrackingInfo);
    }
    else if( portalBarcodeGrid.requestInfo.NextApplicableStep == 'SHIP_LOAN' || portalBarcodeGrid.requestInfo.NextApplicableStep == 'RECEIVE_LOAN' ){
        portalBarcodeGrid.createBarcodeGridEmptyRows( gridSelector,6 )  
    }
    else if( portalBarcodeGrid.requestInfo.NextApplicableStep == 'RETURN_LOAN' || portalBarcodeGrid.requestInfo.NextApplicableStep == 'COMPLETE_LOAN' ){
        portalBarcodeGrid.createBarcodeGridRows( gridSelector, portalBarcodeGrid.requestInfo.LoanTrackingInfo );    
    }
},


createBarcodeGridEmptyRows : function( gridSelector,noOfRows ) {
    var gridId = gridSelector.split('#')[1];

    for( var i = 0; i < noOfRows; i++ ){

        var obj = {};

        obj.LocalNumber = '';

        if( i == 0 )
            obj.ProcessStatus = portalBarcodeGrid.processStatus.PENDING;
        else
            obj.Status = '';

        portalBarcodeGrid.requestProcessStatus.LoanTrackingInfo.push( obj );

        $( gridSelector ).jqGrid( 'addRowData', gridId+'_tr-'+(i+1), obj );
    }

    // select first row of the grid
    var rowId = $( gridSelector ).getDataIDs()[0];
    portalBarcodeGrid.selectBarcodeGridRow( rowId );
},


createBarcodeGridRows : function( gridSelector, loanTrackingInfo ) {
    var loanTrackingCount = loanTrackingInfo == undefined || loanTrackingInfo.length == 0 ? 1 : loanTrackingInfo.length;
    var numOfRows = Math.ceil((loanTrackingCount + 1) / 6 ) * 6;
    var lastDataRowId = 0;

    portalBarcodeGrid.createBarcodeGridEmptyRows(gridSelector, numOfRows);

    var arrayRef = loanTrackingInfo;
    var gridId = gridSelector.split('#')[1];
    var getArrDataId = $( gridSelector ).jqGrid( 'getDataIDs' );

    for( var i = 0; i <  arrayRef.length; i++ ){
        $( gridSelector ).jqGrid( 'setCell', getArrDataId[i], 'LocalNumber', arrayRef[i].LocalNumber );

        if(arrayRef[i].LoanStatusComplete)
            $( gridSelector ).jqGrid( 'setCell', getArrDataId[i], 'ProcessStatus',  portalBarcodeGrid.processStatus.PROCESSSUCCESS );
        else
            $( gridSelector ).jqGrid( 'setCell', getArrDataId[i], 'ProcessStatus',  portalBarcodeGrid.processStatus.PENDING );

        lastDataRowId = getArrDataId[i];
    }

    if(portalBarcodeGrid.requestInfo.reOpenMode){
        portalBarcodeGrid.addPendingMsg( gridSelector, gridId, lastDataRowId );
    }
},

addPendingMsg : function( gridSelector, gridIdToAppendToRowId, lastDataRowId ) {
    var pendingRowNum = lastDataRowId.split( '-' )[ 1 ];
    portalBarcodeGrid.addPendingRow( gridSelector, gridIdToAppendToRowId+'_tr-'+(++pendingRowNum) );
},

addPendingRow : function ( gridSelector,rowId ) {
    portalBarcodeGrid.selectBarcodeGridRow( rowId );
    $( gridSelector ).jqGrid( 'setCell', rowId, 'ProcessStatus', portalBarcodeGrid.processStatus.PENDING );
},

addEditableProperty : function( gridSelector,rowId ){
    console.log(" addEditableProperty ");

    var prevTdText = $.trim( $( '#'+rowId ).prev('tr').find('td:first').text() );
    var rowNum = rowId.split( '-' )[ 1 ];

    if( rowNum == 1 ) {
        $(gridSelector).jqGrid( 'setColProp', 'LocalNumber', { editable : true } );
        $( gridSelector ).jqGrid( 'editRow', rowId, true, '', '', '', '', portalBarcodeGrid.getRowData );
    }

    if( rowNum > 1 ) {
        if( prevTdText.length < 1 ){
            $( gridSelector ).jqGrid( 'setColProp', 'LocalNumber', { editable : false } );
        }
        else{
            $( gridSelector ).jqGrid( 'setColProp', 'LocalNumber', { editable : true } );
            $( gridSelector ).jqGrid( 'editRow', rowId, true, portalBarcodeGrid.addRows( rowId ), '', '', '' , portalBarcodeGrid.getRowData );
        }
    }
},

addRows : function( rowId ) {
    console.log(" addRows ");

    var gridSelector =  '#'+ portalBarcodeGrid.getGridSelectorId( rowId );

    var gridId = gridSelector.split( '#' )[ 1 ];

    var lastrowid = $( gridSelector ).jqGrid( 'getDataIDs' ).pop();
    var prevTD = $.trim( $( '#'+rowId ).prev( 'tr' ).find( 'td:first' ).text());

    if ( rowId == lastrowid ) {
        if( prevTD.length > 1 ) {
            var rowId = lastrowid.split('-')[1];
            for ( var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                var obj = {};
                var addRow = $( gridSelector ).jqGrid( 'addRowData', gridId+'_tr-'+(++rowId),obj );
            }
        }   
    }
},

getRowData : function( rowId,result ) {
    console.log(" getRowData ");

    var gridSelector =  '#'+ portalBarcodeGrid.getGridSelectorId( rowId );

    var gridDataObj = $( gridSelector ).jqGrid( 'getRowData', rowId );

    if( $.trim(gridDataObj.LocalNumber) != 0 ){

        var barcodeDuplicate = portalBarcodeGrid.getDuplicateBarcode( gridSelector, rowId, gridDataObj );

        if( !barcodeDuplicate ) {
            $( gridSelector ).jqGrid( 'setCell', rowId, 'ProcessStatus', portalBarcodeGrid.processStatus.PROCESSSUCCESS );
            var rowNum = rowId.split('-')[1];
            var nextTrId =  $( '#'+rowId ).next( 'tr' ).attr( 'id' );

            //get the next row in grid and put focus onto it 
            portalBarcodeGrid.selectBarcodeGridRow( nextTrId );
        }
        else {
            $( '#'+rowId ).find( ':input' ).select();
            $(gridSelector).jqGrid( 'restoreRow', rowId ,true );
            portalBarcodeGrid.selectBarcodeGridRow( rowId );
        }
    }
    else{
        //$('#divError').text("Please enter a Barcode");
        $( gridSelector ).jqGrid( 'restoreRow', rowId, true );
    }
},

getDuplicateBarcode : function ( gridSelector, rowId) {
    console.log(" getDuplicateBarcode ");

    var barcodeDuplicate = false ;
    var currentRowData = $( gridSelector ).jqGrid( 'getRowData', rowId );
    var gridRows = $( gridSelector ).find( 'tr' );

    for( var i = 0; i < gridRows.length; i++){
        gridRowId = $ (gridRows [i]).attr( 'id' );

        if ( currentRowData.LocalNumber == $( gridRows[i] ).find( 'td:first' ).text() && rowId != gridRowId ) {
            $('#divError').text("Duplicate Barcode");
            barcodeDuplicate = true;
        }
    }
    return  barcodeDuplicate;
},
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Found a Solution
The jqGrid library doesnt allow to edit the row on error is because they unbind the enter key event in save function . 
**The Fix**
Remove this line of code from the library itself and it worked :

```
$(ind).removeClass("jqgrid-new-row").unbind("keydown");
```

Hope it helps to someone !!!